# MySQL query works fine one local windows dev environment, but not on linux server

Tags: mysql, node.js, linux, rest, deployment

I'm working on a REST API using Node.js and TypeScript. I use Sequelize for my db stuff.

I have some queries (mostly raw queries executed through Sequelize) that run perfectly fine in my development environment (Windows 10 with the 10.4.24-MariaDB MySQL server that comes with XAMPP) but give me syntax errors when I deploy the project to my VPS server (running ubuntu 22, having the 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 MySQL server installed on it).

For example, I have this piece of code somewhere in my backend:

```js
await db.query(`
    INSERT INTO point_transactions (userId, type, amount, associatedId, createdAt, updatedAt)
    SELECT userId, ${PointTransactionType.WON_FROM_QUIZ}, ${participantsCount} - rank + 1,
    '${quizId}', NOW(), NOW()
    FROM ranks
    WHERE quizId = '${quizId}';
`, {
    type: QueryTypes.INSERT,
    transaction: t
});
```

(I know that I can use replacemnents and stuff, but that's not the topic).

This will result in a query like this:

```sql
 INSERT INTO point_transactions (userId, type, amount, associatedId, createdAt, updatedAt)
    SELECT userId, 0, 0 - rank + 1, '24', NOW(), NOW()
    FROM ranks
    WHERE quizId = '24';
```

This query runs perfectly fine on my local machine with the specs above and does exactly what I want it to do, but on my Linux server, it throws the following error:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ 1, '24', NOW(), NOW() 
    FROM ranks
    WHERE quizId ' at line 2
```

I think this might be related to version differences, maybe the server version of mysql does not support some feature needed to parse this query? I couldn't find anything useful.

If possible, I want to fix the issue without cahnging the query (for multiple reasons, one being that this is not the only problematic query in the code!).

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding parentheses around the expression `(${participantsCount} - rank + 1)`

Comment: @kampit That didn't help unfortunately, still says: near '+ 1),...

Comment: Try `WHERE quizId = '${quizId.replace(/'/g, "\\'")}';`

Comment: @kampit This didn't help either. Judginf rom the error message, it seems to have a problem with the + 1 part or something that comes after it.

Comment: Okay last, try using the `CAST` or `CONVERT`. `CAST(${participantsCount} AS UNSIGNED) - rank + 1`

Comment: @kampit Although I'm sure it won't ever returna negative number, I tried it, but now I get [....for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED)  - rank + 1), ...]

Comment: Is there by any chance a different version of mysql than the one that I mentioned that might accept this syntax?

Comment: Try add `console.log('quizID:', quizID);`
`console.log('participantsCount:', participantsCount);` before await db.query

Comment: @kampit I checked that already, no problem at all, it's even working on local MariaDB as I said, it's just the server's mysql complaining about the syntax for some reason...

Comment: Thanks to slaakso's answer, turned out that "rank" is considered a keyword now! I need to sorround it with backticks. Thanks a lot for your help! :) @kampit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rank` is a reserved word in MySQL 8.0. Use backticks around the column name.

Comment: Assuming that the language sould've warned me about such a mistake, I would never ever think about that! You just saved me, thanks a ton! :)